# What's the best way to issue a 301 redirect in this situation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a PHP5/Zend Framework 1.8.1 web site which is located at:

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

The older version of this site, which infuriatingly, is still maintained by google's index was located at:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/DEFAULT.ASP
```

So a lot of people are requesting the above link and hitting a dead end.

I figure, the way to fix this would be to issue a 301 redirect to take him to the new site. The two ways to do this that spring to mind are:

1. The first way I thought of was to add a rewrite rule to our .htaccess . Our site implementation is PHP5 / Zend Framework 1.8.1, so there's an existing rewrite rule in the .htaccess (as per Zend Framework MVC requirement) which is:

   ```
   RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|jpeg)$ index.php
   ```

   As a mod_rewrite noob, I did a bit of googling and came up with the following to handle the redirect:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/foo/DEFAULT.ASP
   RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/foo$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   I added those lines to the .htaccess, but they do not work.
2. The second way I thought of is to use `Zend_Router_Route_Static` as follows:

   ```
   $router = $frontController->getRouter();
   $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('foo/DEFAULT.ASP', array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'index'));
   $router->addRoute('foo', $route);
   ```

   This redirects to the correct page, but I have no idea how to set a 301 header as well, plus it's quite inelegant having those lines of code in my `bootstrap.php`

Can anyone offer any advice on how to deal with this situation? I would like to know all or any of:

1. How to get the rewrite rule to work
2. How to do a '301' with
   `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` if
   possible.
3. Is there another way that I'm
   missing?
4. Which is the better way and why?
5. Why isn't google figuring this out?
   It has been nearly half a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (make sure you put it before the Zend rule):

```
RewriteRule ^foo/DEFAULT.ASP /foo [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure why Google isn't figuring it out - are you sure you're giving a proper 404 status code?  You can check by looking at the headers - in Firefox I use [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, giving it a go now.

Comment: I did that, but it did not work, exactly the same result as before. Any idea?

Comment: Did you put it before the other rule?

Comment: Tried. It seems to know when I enter the DEFAULT.ASP URL, but browser says 'could not connect to server'. Strange.

Comment: That's odd... See what Location header you're being sent (if you're getting that far).

Comment: Greg - my own stupid fault. I firebugged it, the 301 was happening, but apache was taking the host from the etc, which was incorrect. Thanks a gazillion!

Answer (score 2):

I recently solved a similar problem by adding

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp
```

to the .htaccess file, which makes the server run .asp files with php.

Then I created a file default.asp containing header( 'Location: /', etc ) to replace the one that Google was looking for. I had a few other .asp files with complex parameters that needed to be transformed into new URLs before redirecting, in some cases requiring a database lookup, so it was handy being able to write everything in PHP so I could use include files from other parts of the project.

Comment: +1 - Thanks Steve, interesting way to solve the problem! I never would have thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect permanent /foo/DEFAULT.ASP /foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved your problem, and this wouldn't be a good solution for your issue, but here's another resource that others might find useful if they were attracted to this thread by your question:

http://www.refreshinglyblue.com/2008/10/28/zend-framework-redirect-the-easy-way/

He's suggesting the "Redirector Zend Controller Action Helper" to redirect internal urls.

P.S. If anyone does use _redirect, make sure to pass in the 301 redirect code (if that's what you want) since it defaults to 302.

Comment: I'm trying to use $this->_redirect($url, array('code'=>301)), but I in the http headers I get 302 instead of 301. Any idea why?